# Credential should be scoped to a valid region when reaching DynamoDB from ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-ecs

I'm setting up an ECS instance for my backend that interacts with DynamoDB tables

The tasks are running, the healthcheck has passed and the tasks have been assigned with a role that should grant access to those tables

But when I call the API to interact with the database, it shows me this error

```
InvalidSignatureException: Credential should be scoped to a valid region.
```

The role contains this policies
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1Q14.png

And this are the env variables for the task definition

```html
"environment": [
        {
          "name": "AWS_REGION",
          "value": "eu-west-2"
        },
        {
          "name": "DATABASE_URL",
          "value": "http://dynamodb.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "PORT",
          "value": "3000"
        },
        {
          "name": "REFERRAL_CHARS",
          "value": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        },
        {
          "name": "USERS_TABLE",
          "value": "SparadoxUsers"
        }
      ],
```

Comment: I don't see any problems here. It is possibly a problem with your code. Do you have a region hard-coded in your code (perhaps with a typo in it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue with roles, more so the request itself. Typically you would see this issue when you sign a request for 1 region (eu-west-1) and the you submit that request to a second region (eu-west-2).

My suggestion is to take a close look at how you make your API call and how you define the region and endpoint in your DynamoDB client.

Comment: Thanks! I checked my code and saw I wasn't passing the access key and secret key to AWS.configure